# changing user password with windows sc.exe config command is not working

Tags: windows, command-line, passwords

I am trying to change the user password with sc.exe config command. I used the command

```
sc.exe config ol_cognoscm obj= .\informix password= **********
```

I did see the password changed successfully message after running the command, but service refuses to start and service still holds the old password only.

Is there a way to change the user password on windows through command line?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using services.msc UI to set the password?

Are you sure that the password is correct? Can you try launching command prompt with the same user credentials?

Does the account have run as Service account right?

Assuming you want to update the username and password that the service is going to log on with. This will not change the user's credentials

Comment: Thanks for the response. If i set it manually( through services.msc) it works fine. But i want to automate that process. Here i have service which will run with specific user account( here informix).  I want change that informix user password through command line. Is there a specific step i missed? or  Is there a problem with service account?  please help me to understand this.Thanks

Comment: Can you verify from services.msc, that the service is stopped when you do the change from command line and the username is as per what you passed from the command line? Try replacing .\with Machine-Name\

Comment: No luck with replacing .\ with machine-name\

Comment: How did you figure that the service is holding to the old password?

Comment: The way i get to know that the new password is effective or not. I will try to login to the machine with the new password, in this case failed. But am able to login to the machine with the old password.  BTW am trying to change password of the service account not the local account, not sure if this makes any difference.

Comment: If its a local service account, that account never has a password. If its a normal user account that you are using as a account to run the service in, the procedure to change its password is via AD or Account Management in control panel and not SC.exe